# Order differently until success

Tags: php, while-loop

**I decided to disable the space buttom while registering. In case that your first and last name are like someone's else, only in that case, you'll be asked to add a username and login with him.**

In my login form you need to write your first and last name in the same input, but in my database the first and the last name are in different columns. Using php's explode() function I'll separate the words to array, and then easily I'll check it in the database. But what about the people with the two first or last names? For example Sacha Baron Cohen. Is there a way (if so, I guess with while) to make loops until success? I mean to:

- **first:** Sacha Baron **last:** Cohen
- **first:** Sacha **last:** Baron Cohen
- **first:** Sacha **last**: Cohen
- **first:** Sacha **last**: Baron
- **last:** Sacha **first**: Baron Cohen

and so on until success or after it tried all the options? How to do it?
Thanks!

(I think that it will be faster if I'll take the first and last name of all the people with the password that the has write and then it won't need to connect every time to the database)

**I'm talking about the singing in. The first and last names stored in the database. They were asked about it (two separate fields) while registering.**

Comment: You can't know someone's first and last name. Some first names are joined by a `-` but sometimes people just have 3 first names without joining characters. So in the end you can only gamble what's the first- and what's the last name. You always need to ask the user to insert their first- and last name separately. Joining the first and last name from the database fields and try to match them isn't safe either and very taxing on your database. It could result in a conflict where a unique combination of first name and last name can be the same, but not actually the same first- and last name.

Comment: It's always best to assign usernames instead of having to sift through surnames containing two. If this is for a members page, which I'm assuming it is. You could use `LIKE` with `%name%` or `name%` wildcard or `FULLTEXT` search, however there are other methods using the `IN` clause.

Comment: @Allendar I'm talking about the singing in. The first and last names stored in the database. They were asked about it (two separate fields) while registering.

Comment: @VladGincher I know Vlad, but it won't work sadly.

Comment: Why don't you use concat mysql function and query the input with it

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm trying to make the registration form as short as I can. In the registration you are asked to write your first and last name, email and password (and of course, a recaptcha). The username input is only in case that the name is already taken (I even found a facebook profile of someone named Vlad Gincher and it wasn't myne).

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's the point I was pointing out tho. Concatting the first- and last name is not reliable. There can be situation where a first- and last name can result in the same full name, yet having different first- and last names. Trust me, I already had this problem in a live environment. Please refrain from doing it. When the CONCAT matches more than 1 set (excluding the password) you have a big issue, that can also be hard to detect (no errors) later by other developers.

Comment: @Allendar But there is still a password; While registering you'll be asked to enter a strong password and it won't continue until your password will green (If 3 of them are true: 8 charset, numbers, letters, big letters (ABC..) and so on), there is no way that they'll have the same password.

Comment: @engvrdr I don't understand you.

Comment: @VladGincher No it won't. It's almost impossible, but if both users insert each other's password it's still a security risk. ***If*** you know it can happen, you should prevent it, never ignore it. It's just not stable enough for good security.

Comment: Sorry i'm on mobile right now there is a mysql function called concat you can use it like  select * from users whre concat (firstname,' ',lastname) = $input

Comment: @Allendar so what do you suggest? Maybe I should write in the registering form, only if the first and last name are like someone's else, that they, but only they, will need to login with the email only? Or to prevent spaces on the name fields and then while logging will be only one option?

Comment: What you could do is offer them a username, or give one themselves, while registering. If they register and the username already exists, just generate a prefix or suffix to it. Otherwise, yes, the email address. On the systems at my work we don't even indicate when you use *forgot password* that the data is known in our database. So actually saying that you already know the name combination would give away stored information from your database. Of course with an email (being unique), while registering, you just can't avoid it.

Comment: You should be checking if an `email` already exists instead of actual names. There can be 500 `John Smiths'` and `Jane Does'` along with `John Paul Jones'` You can't discriminate on someone's given names.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work.

Think about this example:

There is a person called:

**first**: Steve Marc
**last**: Henderson

Another person is called:

**first**: Steve
**last**: Marc Henderson

With your method you would not get an exact answer when scanning for "Steve Marc Henderson". 
The only possible way of doing this would be to limit the input to one first name and one last name when people sign in.

Comment: But there is still a password; While registering you'll be asked to enter a strong password and it won't continue until your password will green (If 3 of them are true: 8 charset, numbers, letters, big letters (ABC..) and so on), there is no way that they'll have the same password.

Comment: I am sorry but this is a very bad way of thinking when programming, there is always the possibility that they have the same name and password, this is why every platform uses unique identifiers (e.g. nickname or email) which can only exist once. When programming you need to make sure that everything is 100% exact...